# How to properly implement an execute-function-on-each-element with CUDA?

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda

I have a class representing one or several containers of objects. The class offers a function to run a callback for each of the elements. A simple implementation could look like:

```
struct MyData{
    Foo* foo;
    void doForAllFoo(std::function<void(Foo)> fct){
       for( /* all indices i in foo */){
         fct(f[i]); 
       }
    } 
}
```

Driving code:

```
MyData d = MyData(...);
TypeX param1 = create_some_param();
TypeY param2 = create_some_more_param();
d.doForAll([&](Foo f) {my_function(f, param1, param2);});
```

I think this is a good solution for flexible callbacks on a container.

Now I'd like to parallelize this with CUDA. I'm not quite sure about what is allowed with lambdas in CUDA and I'm also not sure about compilation for `__device__` and `__host__`.

I can (and will probably have to) change `MyData`, but I'd like to have no trace of the CUDA background in the driving code, except that I have to allocate memories in a CUDA-accessible way of course.

I think a minimal example would be very helpful.

Comment: Perhaps I missed it, but did you actually ask a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Well...I ask how I should do that. Furthermore, I say that probably a minimal example would best answer the question.

Comment: The Thrust library which ships with CUDA already has an implementation of `std::for_each` which works on iterable sequences in GPU memory using a user supplied function or functor. Would that be of any help?

Comment: `std::for_each` seems EXACTLY what I'm looking for. Let's test...

Answer (score 1):

Before you start to write the C style CUDA kernel function, you could check [Thrust](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html) library. It is part of the CUDA and provide high level abstract for simple GPU algorithm development.

Here is a code example to show the use of function object and lamda expression with thrust.

https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/lambda.cu

Even with Thrust, you still need to use `__device__` and `__host__` to ask the compiler to generate device code and host code for you. Since there's no place to put them in standard C++ lamda expression, you probably need to write longer code.